# node-gyp error while depoloying rails 6 with vue app on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, heroku, yarnpkg

I'm trying to deploy rails 6 with vue app on heroku, but I'm getting this error:

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
   error /tmp/build_c242c7d78580af478535f5a344ff701e/node_modules/fibers: Command failed.
   Exit code: 127
   Command: node build.js || nodejs build.js
   Arguments: 
   Directory: /tmp/build_c242c7d78580af478535f5a344ff701e/node_modules/fibers
   Output:
   node-gyp not found! Please ensure node-gyp is in your PATH--
   Try running: `sudo npm install -g node-gyp`
   /bin/sh: 1: nodejs: not found
   spawn node-gyp ENOENT
   info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.

   Precompiling assets failed.

   Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
   Push failed
```

I tried to search for solution everywhere, but it seems like no one else had this problem. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I didn't add node buildpack to heroku app, adding it fixed the problem

Comment: Apart from this I had to move it before `heroku/rails` buildpack